# Drag and drop webparts | Sharepoint 2010 | User preference

Tags: my-site, personalization, drag-and-drop

In our Sharepoint 2010 application, user wants to have the ability to choose sections (webparts) they want to see in each page and the position they should be placed on, each section (webpart) could be dragged around on placed anywhere in the page (the kind of flexibility that we have it during design time). These settings should be stored for each user as part of their preferences.

Can sharepoint mysite be used here? If so how to use it in this scenario? If not, please share your ideas on the same.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is called [Personalized Pages](http://www.sharepointskeptic.com/2012/personalize-this-page-in-sharepoint-2010/). It's a little obscure, but allows you to do exactly what you are asking: That people can personalise their page, meaning they can change the content on the page, the webparts, the order of the webparts. It's similar to personalized views on lists and personalized webparts (kind of). It may be your users need a special permission level (there is one specifically for personalization) before they are allowed to do this.